# alert fire before the db transaction statement in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT userid FROM user', [], function (tx,results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            userId = results.rows.item(i).userid;
            alert(results.rows.item(i).userid );
        }
    }, dbErrorHandler);
}, dbErrorHandler);

alert(userId);
```

In above code the last alert is displayed before the previous db transaction statement.

Why does it happens like this? Could someone suggest solutions?

Comment: It's because inserting into the database is asynchronous, hence the callback.

Comment: @adeneo so what is the solution to get data(userid)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an asynchronous call, you need to display your alert in the success callback :

```
db.transaction(selectDB, errorCB, successCB);

function selectDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT userid FROM user', [], function (tx,results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            userId = results.rows.item(i).userid;
            alert(results.rows.item(i).userid );
        }
    }, dbErrorHandler)
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    alert(err);
    dbErrorHandler;
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert(userId);
}
```